# Howto focus bootstrap-select element via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap Select Dropdown in Spring:

```
<form:select name="participant-picker" multiple="false" path="participants" cssClass="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Teilnehmer..." data-width="100%">
    <form:options
        items="${participants}"
        itemValue="enrolmentNumber"
        itemLabel="description" />
</form:select>
```

After execution:

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Teilnehmer..." name="participant-picker" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="1234687">Nachname121, Vorname122 (1234687)</option>
    <option value="1234688">Nachname122, Vorname123 (1234688)</option>
</select>
```

Please keep in mind, that Bootstrap dynamically adds multiple divs for the dropdown and other stuff.

Now i want to dynamically set the focus to this select element. This is not working:

```
$('select[name=participant-picker]').focus()
```

Comment: add up a fiddle for this please, seems like, your piece of code looks fine. but for better understanding fiddle would be a good option.

Comment: By the way, doing the same on an input field instead of the select element is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved: When using Bootrap selectpickeryou have to set the focus to the button element generated by Bootstrap itself below the select element and not to the select element itself.

Answer (score 1):

simply assign an id and focus to it using that id as

```
<form:select id="one" name="participant-picker" multiple="false" path="participants" cssClass="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Teilnehmer..." data-width="100%">
<form:options
    items="${participants}"
    itemValue="enrolmentNumber"
    itemLabel="description" />
</form:select>
```

then use

```
$('#one').focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add quotes ?

Something like this :

```
$('select[name="participant-picker"]').focus()
```

I already had some troubles with this.

Comment: Selector is not the problem, entering $('#participant-picker') on the console returns the correct element

Answer (score 0):

No need quotes `[name="participant-picker"]`.

May be you have more than one element with name `participant-picker`.?
In this case only first element will be founded and set focus on it.

Add specific id to each element witd name `participant-picker` for example `id="e1"` and try `$('#e1').focus()`

Also try `[name^=participant-picker]` if the name differ at end ex: `a1,a2` for this try  `[name^=a]` will find `a1 and a2 ... an`.

Also try some like this 
 `$('[name=participant-picker]').each(function(){$(this).css('background-color','red');});` to see that elements selector `$('[name=participant-picker]').` found

Comment: Entering $('#participant-picker') on the console returns the correct element, but $('#participant-picker').focus() is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions in this post but none worked for me with bootstrap. If you just want it to focus on page load, the easiest way is to use `autofocus`

In this case it would look like this:

```
<form:select name="participant-picker" multiple="false" path="participants" cssClass="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Teilnehmer..." data-width="100%" autofocus>
    <form:options
        items="${participants}"
        itemValue="enrolmentNumber"
        itemLabel="description" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

By executing the 'toggle' parameter twice on the selectpicker, will do the focus.

```
$('.sel').selectpicker('toggle');
$('.sel').selectpicker('toggle');
```